# Using "Retired"/Extra slots (82-95) on Yubikey

Tags: openssl, yubikey

Most tutorials that cover smartcard functionality of the Yubikeys use slots

- **9a** (PIV Authentication),
- **9c** (Digital Signature) and
- **9d** (Key Management).

However, there are also [slots **82-95** (Retired Key Management)](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Introduction/Certificate_slots.html) available:

> These slots are only available on the YubiKey 4 & 5. They are meant
> for previously used Key Management keys to be able to decrypt earlier
> encrypted documents or emails. In the YubiKey 4 & 5 all 20 of them are
> fully available for use.

I would like to use more than one slot for digital signatures, so I would use slots 9c and, say, 84 for two different certificates.

My questions are:

- Is this scheme "valid"? (i.e., using slots 82-95 for digital signatures, not encryption/decryption)
- How can I configure slot 84 to use the same PIN policy (require PIN/touch for **every** action) that slot 9c has?
- How can I use `openssl ca` to sign data with key/cert from slot 84?

Comment: isn't this a question for Yubikey support?

Comment: Answers from developers with experience in this space would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up: usually YubiKey is used with gpg, and uses the pgp format, it supports various bells and whistles. YubiKey PIV slots use raw `RSA or ECC key and cert`[0].

Additionally, while the common 4 pgp slots support 4096 bit keys, the PIV slots are spec-ed[1] up to 2048 bits.

1. Generate raw RSA key. You can use `puttygen` or any other tool instead.

`openssl genrsa -out secret.pem 2048`

2. Extract the public key:

`openssl rsa -in secret.pem -pubout -out public.pem`

3. Upload the secret key to the PIV slot, using the `YubiKey SDK`, `yubico-piv-tool` or `YubiKey Manager CLI`:

`ykman piv keys import --pin 123456 --pin-policy NEVER --touch-policy ALWAYS 95 secret.pem`

4. Encrypt a test message using the public key:

`echo "hello world" | openssl rsautl -inkey public.pem -pubin -encrypt -oaep -out msg.encrypted`

5. Decrypt using the SDK:

```
using Yubico.YubiKey;
using Yubico.YubiKey.Piv;
using Yubico.YubiKey.Cryptography;

var msg_encrypted = File.ReadAllBytes("msg.encrypted");

var device = YubiKeyDevice.FindAll().First();

using (var piv = new PivSession(device))
{
    var decrypted_raw = piv.Decrypt(0x95, msg_encrypted);

    byte[] output;

    RsaFormat.TryParsePkcs1Oaep(decrypted_raw, RsaFormat.Sha1, out output);

    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output)); // "hello world"
};
```

If you are only interested in signing, you may not need the SDK[2].

[0] https://docs.yubico.com/yesdk/users-manual/application-piv/slots.html

[1] https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-piv-tool/issues/58

[2] https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/Actions/signing.html

Comment: Although this is useful information, I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: Since the question is specifically about signing, can you modify your answer to talk about that?

Comment: Nope. I don't use Yubikey for signing and have no direct experience with it. This question was unanswered for 11 months. It asked about how to use the extra slots. I shared my experience and gave enough direction for those interested in signing to know where to look at. Only to be downvoted, terrible website.